# Custom Scrollbar and Chrome

Tags: javascript, css

So I wanted to use a custom scroll bar to make the website I am creating more attractive.  I found out about a script called fleXcroll. Basically on the fleXcroll website when I click anywhere inside my scrollable content, there is a large yellow border around the entire wrapper.  I have no idea why this is happening because on the fleXcroll website when I click inside scrollable content, this border doesnt appear and same thing goes for firefox.  When I click in firefox or IE the content appears as it should.
Anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?

Here is a link to the site and please provide kind/constructive comments. This is my first time coding a website.

[go to the flavors page](http://www.jamesendres.com/CupcakeMojo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix that by adding `outline: none` to the parent div. So the styles for `#menu` will be:

```
#mainContent #menu {
    clear: both;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 620px;
    outline: none;
}
```

BTW that is a very delicious site.

Comment: Thank you very much! to both of your answers, I used a random gen to pick which one I would give the check mark to :)

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why it's happening, as I've never used your flexcroll, however, the fix is easy:

```
.flexcroll{
  outline: none;
}
```

Add this to any stylesheet that is shared cross-site and you should be good.

Comment: Thank you very much! to both of your answers, I used a random gen to pick which one I would give the check mark to :)